# is it possible to use KeyChain / ssh-agent with apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-ssl, keychain

There are a lots a question (and duplicates) on serverfault asking how restart Apache without the passphrase prompt.
Two solutions are proposed :

- removing the password from the key
- the apache directive that supply the key to Apache (SSLPassPhraseDialog)

This question is not a duplicate of the following one that deals with the two exposed answers:
[SSL password on apache2 restart](https://serverfault.com/questions/71043/ssl-password-on-apache2-restart)

For me it is the same level of security, not necessarily a bad one, but often a bad one.

I'm wondering if it is possible to use KeyChain and an ssh-agent to avoid storing a key without a password or a password in clear in a file, or if there are other alternatives.

This would allow restarting Apache without a passphrase, unless of course the server is rebooted.

Does any body successfully implemented it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately this is not possible. The SSH agent can only prove that you possess a certain private key, it has no functionality to either give access to that key or use it for decrypting a secret.