# What is the passphrase-file in apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I'm referring to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/71043/ssl-password-on-apache2-restart?s=275b3be7-5cca-45ea-82c9-99f99cbb6901) question.
What is the passphrase-file mentioned in here? Please clarify.

Comment: You may be interested in visiting [SU] and [Unix.SE] to gain more knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

It's a shell script that is used to give apache the password it needs to unlock the key to an SSL certificate.

Comment: what is a shell script? where should I run this?

Comment: Questions on Server Fault are expected to relate to professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration within the scope defined in the FAQ. If you are unfamiliar with the concept of shell script, this is not the place to post your question.