# Rebooting AWS EC2 instance not coming back online

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

About 40 minutes ago, I restarted my AWS EC2 instance using the admin panel. A moment later, the instance state was "running" again, and the status checks continued to pass. After about 20 minutes, though, the phpMyAdmin panel is refusing to load (timing out), as are SSH attempts into the server.

I tried another restart, but the same is holding true. CPU usage dropped to 0% over this period, so the server is clearly offline.

[image: Status checks]

Any ideas as to what could be causing this or how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

In response to @c4urself, I looked at the logs, and found the following at the very bottom. It appears to be asking for a password. Anyone know how to get past this?

> Server www.mydomain.com:443 (RSA) Enter pass phrase:

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It seems like your instance is failing to boot*. Go to "Actions" -> "Instance Settings" -> "Get System Log" and see if you get any valid output there.

There are a number of things that could be wrong, I usually test-reboot instances to make sure they'll come back up properly after running my configuration management tool (you do have one right?) before "comitting" to use that instance. A common culprit that I've run into is a misconfigured `/etc/fstab` without the `nobootwait` flag on a disk that's failing to mount.

If your root disk is EBS you could attempt detaching and reattaching it to another instance to try to salvage out any files that were there previously. If you're needing to do this you probably don't have backups and you probably don't have a configuration management tool, fix that first.

**Update**

I'm pretty sure you're running into: [SSL password on apache2 restart](https://serverfault.com/questions/71043/ssl-password-on-apache2-restart)

Comment: @rebello95 See my update

Comment: Interesting, that looks like it might be it. Any idea how to do this without being able to SSH into the server, etc.?

Comment: Like I said, you could detach the drive, attach to another instance, fix the file(s) and reattach. See for example: http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-fix-ebs-root