# Rebooted and now apache2 is listening on port 80 after startup but not responding to requests

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, apache-2.4

Ran

```
sudo apt-get update       
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Everything was fine. Rebooted. Web server was down. IP not responding to requests on port 80

sudo apachectl start says:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
```

Which is true, its in use by apache2:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1124/apache2
```

So I tried

```
sudo apachectl stop
httpd (no pid file) not running
```

Hmmm, thats odd, its clearly running. If I say:

```
sudo kill -9 1124
```

and then

```
sudo apachectl start
```

all is well.

So when bootup triggers apache to start it gets into a hung state where its listening on port 80 but not fully running enough for apachectl commands to work or for it to respond to page requests. But if I kill it and then start it manually all is well. However, after another restart the condition reoccurs.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't just a process hanging around from before the restart? It's possible that the process didn't die off fully when the upgrade was done.

Comment: The situation reoccurs after another restart.

Answer (score 0):

Right after startup

```
ps aux|grep apache
```

showed that

```
/usr/share/apache2/ask-for-passphrase localhost:443 RSA
```

was running which made me realize exactly what was going on.

One of the sites contained an SSL certificate with a passphrase. So when apache was trying to start at boot time it could not continue without someone manually entering the passphrase.

So you have two options to fix this problem:

1. Add a [SSLPassPhraseDialog](https://serverfault.com/questions/71043/ssl-password-on-apache2-restart) directive to your config.
2. [Remove your passphrase](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RemoveSSLCertPassPhrase) (Less secure)